# Android httpurlconnection and basicauthentication

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask, basic-authentication, httpurlconnection

I'm having a really tough nut to crack with a bug. Api being used is v11, honeycomb 3.0
I have a asynctask inside a fragment downloading from a XML api with basic authentication. It works perfectly even when i change the parameters from the fragment within with the edittexts etc. But when i try to mutate a autocompletetextview from outside the fragment, suddenly i get a "no element at line 1. column 0" exception. I tried the androidhttpclient, fiddled with systemprop(http.keepalive), and completly narrowed it down to this method.

```
public void setStations(String a, String b){
    AutoCompleteTextView fromET = (AutoCompleteTextView ) getView().findViewById(R.id.from);  
    fromET.setText(a);

    AutoCompleteTextView toET = (AutoCompleteTextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.to);  
    toET.setText(b);
}
```

When this method executes it botches up my downloadtask somewhere. If i manually edit these textview it works fine.

```
    class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<Reisadvies>> {
        private Exception ex;
        private ProgressDialog pd;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //loadprogressdialog
        }

        protected ArrayList<Reisadvies> doInBackground(String... params) {
            try{
                ex = null;
                return new APIreader().getRA(params[0], params[1], params[2],params[3],params[4],params[5], params[6]);
            }catch (Exception e){
                cancel(true);
                pd.dismiss();
                ex = e;
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Reisadvies> ra){
            //send list to activity
        }

        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
            showError(ex);
        }
    }  

};


public ArrayList<Reisadvies> getRA(String fromStation, String toStation, String viaStation, String dateTime, String departure, String hslAllowed, String yearCard) throws APIException{
    try{
        String uri = url(fromStation, toStation, viaStation, dateTime, departure, hslAllowed,yearCard);
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if (!url.getHost().equals(uc.getURL().getHost())) {
            throw new APIException("HotspotForwadingActive");
        }
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + "username:password"; //base64 encoded
        uc.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
        uc.connect();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        try{
            return (ArrayList<Reisadvies>) new XMLParser().parseRP(in);
        }finally{
            uc.connect();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new APIException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem in doInBackground:

```
pd.dismiss();
```

You can do operations on UI element only in UI Thread. It means that you can do this in onPostExecute method, or, if you want, you can use runOnUiThread method:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        pd.dismiss();
    }
});
```

I hope this is helpful...

Answer (score 0):

You are right about that too, but the problem was different. Just found out that it was to urlencoding. Should have figured that out right away but was throw off by the fact that it worked sometimes with a space in it :)